# Android Studio 3.1 refusing to work

Tags: android, android-studio

Clean installed Android Studio 3.1, created a new Project with all the standard settings, activity_main.xml wont show anything in Preview but a white screen. Any other layouts won't load either.

Tried changing the themes, version of the support library, rebuild and sync project. Nothing helped.

Is there any known bugs to Android Studio 3.1 (Windows) which relate to this?

Comment: What is inside your `activity_main.xml`?

Comment: Use `28.0.0-alpha1` version in your implementation of library files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There some bugs at latest version of android support library

So the solution is come back 
to use 27 SDK version of the SDK, or use an 28.0.0-alpha version